# delete multiple job steps at once in SSMS

Tags: sql-server, ssms, jobs

I have a job in SSMS with about 129 steps. I am trying to clean it up a bit. Is there a way to delete specified job steps quickly? Instead of going into the job and manually hitting delete on all the steps I need to delete?

Comment: http://sqltidbits.com/scripts/search-sql-server-agent-job-steps-specific-keyword-text-or-stored-procedure - find your job, delete corresponding step from sysjobsteps.

Answer (score 2):

Delete all corresponding to given job ID or Name

```
sp_delete_jobstep { [ @job_id = ] job_id | [ @job_name = ] 'job_name' } ,   
     @step_id = 0
```

Comment: Wasn't super clear just reading this but this is the answer.  Setting `@step_id = 0` as per the documentation:  _Calling sp_delete_jobstep with a step_id value of zero deletes all job steps for the job._ [ms docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-delete-jobstep-transact-sql)